# JS: How to format date and time string?

Tags: javascript, datetime, localization

it's the first time I have to deal with localization in JS. Turned out JS has not something like PHP's date time format (`$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')`). Yes, it has `format()` but this method has no arguments.

I have no idea what to do know. I need to set a format string and I am shocked that there is no native support for this.

Solutions? Any JS libs that solve it?

Comment: Try momentJs. Easy to use:
http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Not a duplicate but yes, very similar.

Answer (score 2):

You could try one of the many existing javascript libraries and code snippets.
For example

1. **DateJS** http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/FormatSpecifiers
2. **FormatDate**
   http://www.dzone.com/snippets/javascript-formatdate-function
3. **Date.format** prototype extension
   http://www.jslab.dk/library/date.format
4. **XDate** http://arshaw.com/xdate/
5. **KendoUI**
   http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/globalization/dateformatting
6. **AngularJS** http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date
7. **Google Apps Script**
   https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)
8. **Globalize** https://github.com/jquery/globalize#format_date

and many many [other](http://www.google.com/search?q=string%20format%20date%20javascript)...

Comment: Thanks, great suggestions. Also thanks to the other posters! Will try DateJS and MomentJS.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a list of some great Date formatting libraries:

1. [DateJs](http://www.datejs.com/)  - Datejs is an open-source JavaScript Date Library
2. [MomentJs](http://momentjs.com/) -  A javascript date library for parsing, validating,
   manipulating, and formatting dates.
3. [JQuery UI DateTime](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) - JQuery UI DateTime library
4. [Xdate](http://arshaw.com/xdate/) - A Modern JavaScript Date Library
5. [DP_DateExtensions](http://depressedpress.com/javascript-extensions/dp_dateextensions/) - The DP_DateExtensions library extends the
   JavaScript Date object with new features and functionality.

Answer (score 1):

[Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/)

This is an excellent library which will do what your looking for. Check out the .toString(specifier) API to format it's output.